# Should the Gauge of wire be consistent for DC

Tags: dc

I'm looking at an [ATX Power Supply](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16817151093) with 2 rails each with a specification of 12 volts @ 20 Amps.  That should be a maximum of 240 watts (per rail). The modular plugs/cables that plug into the power supply are less than 20 gauge (probaby 16 or 18).

I have some devices that uses ~10 watts at ~1.0 amp at 12 vdc.  These devices do not have a power supply or male power plug that can plug them directly into the power supply I have to create my own.

I want to purchase these [custom plugs](http://www.mcmelectronics.com/product/82-12675) that use 20 gauge wire to plug into the devices.  I would hack off the end of the modular cables provided with the power supply and connect the wires from modular cables to these plugs.

How do I calculate the maximum number of devices I can plug into the power supply (using just these two rails) with these custom plugs?  And is the limitation based on the 20 gauge plugs?

Comment: the last sentence in first para makes no sense.

Comment: Sorry updated with correct information.

Comment: Very little of this question makes sense. Do you understand that Power = Voltage x Current? Do you understand that smaller AWG numbers means *larger* wire? Please edit this question so it makes some sort of sense.

Comment: Sorry I'm not an electrical engineer, that is why I'm asking here.  I'm pretty sure Current is Amps, and Power is Watts.  I understand that if I was using the perfect wiring (I think) that I could have a maximum of 24 devices based on watts and 200 devices based on amps, so I'm pretty sure it's the lower number (maximum units = 24).  When the gauge of wire changes, I have no idea what happens.  I know if I was using 1000  gauge wire (made up), based on the devices using .1 amp, I would burn the wire up.  I added more information, let me know if it still doesn't make sense.

Comment: 10W at 12v is ~0.92 Amps, not 0.1A. 20 AWG is smaller than 16 AWG, and carries less current, with a higher resistance.

Comment: @Passerby yes sorry that was a typo.  I am aware that 20 is a smaller gauge wire then 16.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going with the maximum given, 1 Amp, 12V, you can have up to 20 per rail. 17 or 18 as to not drive the rail to the limit. And that's if the combined 12V output is actually 480W, as there might be a limit. If the combined output is limited to say 360W, that means you are allowed 240W on Rail A, or 240W on Rail B, but not at the same time. And 12W is fine on 20AWG

Comment: After further conversation with a friend of mine, I understand now that because the device is only using 1 amp/12 watts that 20 AWG is ok even thought the source supports higher.